# How to set Swipe to RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want use `RecyclerView` in my application and i want set **swipe** for `recyclerview`! for example : ***swipe right show edit***, ***swipe left show delete***. such as bottom image : [Image link](http://uploads.im/PMyAl.png)
How can i set it in `RecyclerView`?

Attention : I am an amateur. Please guide me instead of give me negative point! tnx all <3

Comment: Please include the code you are writing in your question. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i can't add a comment , i sent you a post for sharing this tutorial link
you can use this link to understand how to create `Swipe` `ListView` `Buttons` :

[HOW TO CREATE SWIPE LISTVIEW BUTTONS](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/)

Comment: kheyli mamnoon Abbas jan, vali in baraye `ListView` hast, man vase `RecyclerView` mikham. dar in babat chizi dari?

Comment: mitoni azash komak begiri fek nakonam ziad fargh dashte bashan , bazam age didam link behet midam